# Search text in a particular element in the HTML and return the Range object for it

Tags: javascript, dom, full-text-search, dom-traversal, rangy

I want to search for a text in  HTML element and return the  [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object for the text. I wanted to use the range to do some manipulation like highlighting and replacing the text. Similar to Grammarly's error highlighting feature.

What I have tried so far:

1. Loop through the Element's childer to look for the text and construct the Range. But this approach has 2 issues.

**a. it's very slow (350ms)** and
**b.fails to find some texts**

```js
const getRangeofText = (text:string) => {
  const children = document.activeElement;
  let finalNode;
  let parent = children;
  let i = 12;
  let isFound = false;
  while (parent.children.length > 0 && i > 0) {
    i--;
    console.log("I: ", i);
    console.log("traversing through: ", parent.childNodes);
    for (const item of Array.from(parent.childNodes)) {
      console.log("item: ", item);
      if (item.nodeType === 3 && item.textContent.includes(text)) {
        console.log("found in TEXT NODE");
        finalNode = item;
        isFound = true;
      }
      if (item.nodeType === 1 && item.textContent.includes(text)) {
        console.log("found in ELEMENT NODE");
        parent = item as Element;
        finalNode = item;
        isFound = true;
      }
    }
  }

  console.log("final node: ", finalNode);
  // console.log("node type: ", finalNode.nodeType);

  const range = new Range();
  let startNode;
  let endNode;
  let arr = text.split(" ");
  let startWord = arr[0];
  let endWord = arr[arr.length - 1];
  if (finalNode) {
    if (finalNode.nodeType === 1) {
      let childNodes = finalNode.childNodes;
      for (const item of Array.from(childNodes)) {
        if (item.textContent.includes(startWord)) {
          startNode = item;
        }
        if (item.textContent.includes(endWord)) {
          endNode = item;
        }
      }
     

      range.setStart(startNode, 0);
      range.setEndAfter(endNode);
    } else {
      range.setStart(finalNode, 0);
      range.setEnd(finalNode, text.length);
    }

    window.getSelection().addRange(range);
  }
};
```

Here is the [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-kowalevski-msl44g?file=/src/index.js) for the above code.

2. Using [Rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy)'s [findText()](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Text-Range-Module#findtextmixed-searchterm-object-options) method. And this approach is very slow too (200ms)

What other options do I have? Or how can optimize these functions?

Answer (score 0):

```
function getRanges(a) {
  let ranges = [];
  const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  while (window.find(a)) {
    var rng = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    ranges = [...ranges, rng];
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  }
  return ranges;
}

const getRangeElements = (str) => {
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  const ranges = getRanges(str);
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
  return ranges;
};

getRangeElements("Text to search for")
```

This works but it blurs out the page and whatever element (eg. text input) that was focus will get blurred. Any way we can avoid the blur?